# MongoDB - update an existing document in a collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection called `user_roles` and it contains a field called `rights` which is an array of strings.

I want to update a document within `user_roles` collection that has `_id = 5b1509f8b95b4bfe2b638508` by appending a new string element into the `rights` field.

So basically, after this update collection should hold the additional element `"ui.dealers.measures.retrieve"` as shown below.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b1509f8b95b4bfe2b638508"), 
    "type" : "coach", 
    "name" : "Coach", 
    "flavours" : {
        "coach" : NumberInt(1)
    }, 
    "rights" : [
        "ui.dealers.retrieve", 
        "ui.dealers.dossier.retrieve", 
        "ui.dealers.dossier.update", 
        "ui.dealers.documents.retrieve", 
        "ui.dealers.documents.create", 
        "ui.dealers.documents.delete", 
        "ui.dealers.events.retrieve", 
        "ui.dealers.events.create", 
        "ui.dealers.events.update", 
        "ui.dealers.events.export", 
        "ui.dealers.events.delete", 
        "ui.dealers.kpis.retrieve", 
        "ui.dealers.kpis.update", 
        "ui.dealers.blueprints.retrieve", 
        "ui.dealers.blueprints.create", 
        "ui.dealers.gap.retrieve", 
        "ui.dealers.gap.update",
        "ui.dealers.measures.create", 
        "ui.dealers.surveys.retrieve", 
        "ui.dealers.surveys.update",
        "ui.dealers.measures.retrieve"
    ], 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-06-04T09:44:24.394+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-06-04T10:01:56.428+0000")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please try this

```
db.collection.update({_id:ObjectId("5b1509f8b95b4bfe2b638508")},{
$push:{
  "rights":"ui.dealers.measures.retrieve"
}         
})
```

Comment: @HadidAli you can pull that value aswell, just you need to change $push keyword to $pull :)